# SQL INNER JOIN WHEN NULL VALUES

Tags: sql, join, null

Hello guys :) I have a table with 2 fields that are FK from another table. Those fields are idAdviceOwner and idAdviceNotifier. However, only one of them is with a value. I want to validate where or not it has a NULL value in order to choose the other field...Basically I've done this, of course is not running but that's the Idea... hope you guys help me out.

```
select *from notification n
    inner join user u 
    on (n.idUserNotifier=u.idUser)
    inner join advice a on (case WHEN n.idAdviceOwner IS NOT NULL  
                           THEN n.idAdviceOwner=a.idAdvice
                           else n.idAdviceNotifier=a.idAdvice )
    where n.idUser=8
```

Comment: you can use     inner join advice a on COALESCE(n.idAdviceOwner,n.idAdviceNotifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from notification n
    inner join user u 
    on (n.idUserNotifier=u.idUser)
    inner join advice a on case WHEN n.idAdviceOwner IS NOT NULL  
                           THEN n.idAdviceOwner else n.idAdviceNotifier END = a.idAdvice
    where n.idUser=8;
```

Your idea was right but CASE-WHEN-ELSE-END returns an expression, not a condition. That's why you received the error.

Comment: I would write this as `a.idAdvice = coalesce(n.idAdviceOwner, n.idAdviceNotifier)`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Yes, it's shorter. I'd use NVL in Oracle but I don't know the RDBMS used in OP. I know only that case when works there.

Comment: @Multisync . . . `coalesce()` is ANSI standard and basically all databases support it.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I know it's in ANSI but for example Access doesn't support this function as well as Oracle 8i

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the error is, and I don't have a SQL engine handy to test on (I am on the road), but I think what you are trying to do here should basically work, except you probably need to do something along the lines of

```
... on a.idAdvice = (case WHEN n.idAdviceOwner IS NOT NULL  
                           THEN n.idAdviceOwner
                           else n.idAdviceNotifier)
```

Another way is to join to `advice` twice in your query, once with `idAdviceOwner`, and once with `idAdviceNotifier`, and then use `COALESCE` or similar to combine the fields from the two results.